# CSS3 Removing line between two plane when the parent is rotated

Tags: css, 3d

How do I remove the line between the two plane when the parent is rotated? heres the link http://jsfiddle.net/css3guy/KHVWM/1/
I'm using chrome.

```
<div class="world">
      <div class="cube">
       <div class="plane"></div>
       <div class="plane p2"></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use -webkit-perspective: 800px;

Comment: Hi, I updated the code using -webkit-perspective: 800px. But when I animate It the line is still there. here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/css3guy/KHVWM/1/

Comment: set border: 1px solid transparent; for plane class